Relationship between the boundaries of two convex sets
Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a closed convex set contained in a  plane $H$. (The plane $H$ passes through the point  $\mathbf{0}$ and is orthogonal to the unit vector $\hat{\mathcal{r}}\in \mathbb{R}^3$). Assume $\mathbf{0}\notin S$, and define the set  $T=\{\mathbf{x}\in H \,|\, \mathbf{x}=\alpha \mathbf{s},\, 0\leq \alpha\leq 1,\, \mathbf{s}\in S \}$. Geometrically, $T$ represents the set of all convex combinations between $\mathbf{0}$ and each point of $S$. I am looking for a relationship between the boundary of $T$ with the boundary of $S$. Any hint would be warmly appreciated!

A relationship like containment between the boundaries of $T$ and $S$?
